# Fix kernel issues in rescue mode

Tags: centos, boot, kernel, upgrade, grub2

I have updated the kernel in a VPS Centos 7, and after rebooting, the machine is not responding anymore, including with SSH.

I connected to the VPS via a temporary rescue linux machine from where I could mount the VPS filesystem:

```
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/
```

I checked the log file /mnt/var/log/messages and found:

```
- yum: Updated: kernel-tools-libs-3.10.0-1160.80.1.el7.x86_64
- yum: Updated: kernel-tools-3.10.0-1160.80.1.el7.x86_64
- yum: Installed: kernel-3.10.0-1160.80.1.el7.x86_64
- yum: Updated: kernel-headers-3.10.0-1160.80.1.el7.x86_64
- yum: Updated: python-perf-3.10.0-1160.80.1.el7.x86_64
- yum: Updated: 2:microcode_ctl-2.1-73.15.el7_9.x86_64
- systemd: Reloading.
- dracut: dracut-033-572.el7
- dracut: Executing: /sbin/dracut -f /boot/initramfs-3.10.0-1160.80.1.el7.x86_64.img 3.10.0-1160.80.1.el7.x86_64
- dracut: dracut module 'busybox' will not be installed, because command 'busybox' could not be found!
- dracut: dracut module 'plymouth' will not ...
- dracut: dracut module 'plymouth' will not ...
- dracut: dracut module 'crypt' will not ...
- dracut: dracut module 'dmraid' will not ...
- dracut: dracut module 'dmsquash-live-ntfs' will not ...
- dracut: dracut module 'lvm' will not ...
- dracut: dracut module 'mdraid' will not ...
- dracut: dracut module 'multipath' will not ...
- dracut: dracut module 'cifs' will not ...
- dracut: dracut module 'fcoe' will not ...
- dracut: dracut module 'fcoe' will not ...
- dracut: dracut module 'fcoe' will not ...
- dracut: dracut module 'fcoe' will not ...
- dracut: dracut module 'fcoe' will not ...
- dracut: dracut module 'fcoe-uefi' will not ...
- dracut: dracut module 'fcoe-uefi' will not ...
- dracut: dracut module 'fcoe-uefi' will not ...
- dracut: dracut module 'iscsi' will not ...
- dracut: dracut module 'iscsi' will not ...
- dracut: dracut module 'nbd' will not ...
- dracut: dracut module 'biosdevname' will not ...
- dracut: *** Including module: bash ***
- dracut: *** Including module: modsign ***
- dracut: *** Including module: nss-softokn ***
- dracut: *** Including module: i18n ***
- dracut: *** Including module: network ***
- dracut: *** Including module: ifcfg ***
- dracut: *** Including module: btrfs ***
- dracut: *** Including module: kernel-modules ***
- dracut: *** Including module: qemu ***
- dracut: *** Including module: qemu-net ***
- dracut: *** Including module: nfs ***
- dracut: *** Including module: resume ***
- dracut: *** Including module: rootfs-block ***
- dracut: *** Including module: terminfo ***
- dracut: *** Including module: udev-rules ***
- dracut: Skipping udev rule: 40-redhat-cpu-hotplug.rules
- dracut: Skipping udev rule: 91-permissions.rules
- dracut: *** Including module: virtfs ***
- dracut: *** Including module: systemd ***
- dracut: *** Including module: usrmount ***
- dracut: *** Including module: base ***
- dracut: *** Including module: fs-lib ***
- dracut: *** Including module: microcode_ctl-fw_dir_override ***
- dracut: microcode_ctl module: mangling fw_dir
- dracut: microcode_ctl: reset fw_dir to "/lib/firmware/updates /lib/firmware"
- dracut: microcode_ctl: processing data directory  "/usr/share/microcode_ctl/ucode_with_caveats/intel"...
- dracut: microcode_ctl: intel: caveats check for kernel version "3.10.0-1160.80.1.el7.x86_64" passed, adding "/usr/share/microcode_ctl/ucode_with_caveats/intel" to fw_dir variable
- dracut: microcode_ctl: processing data directory  "/usr/share/microcode_ctl/ucode_with_caveats/intel-06-2d-07"...
- dracut: microcode_ctl: intel-06-2d-07: caveats check for kernel version "3.10.0-1160.80.1.el7.x86_64" passed, adding "/usr/share/microcode_ctl/ucode_with_caveats/intel-06-2d-07" to fw_dir variable
- dracut: microcode_ctl: processing data directory  "/usr/share/microcode_ctl/ucode_with_caveats/intel-06-4e-03"...
- dracut: microcode_ctl: kernel version "3.10.0-1160.80.1.el7.x86_64" failed early load check for "intel-06-4e-03", skipping
- dracut: microcode_ctl: processing data directory  "/usr/share/microcode_ctl/ucode_with_caveats/intel-06-4f-01"...
- dracut: microcode_ctl: kernel version "3.10.0-1160.80.1.el7.x86_64" failed early load check for "intel-06-4f-01", skipping
- dracut: microcode_ctl: processing data directory  "/usr/share/microcode_ctl/ucode_with_caveats/intel-06-55-04"...
- dracut: microcode_ctl: intel-06-55-04: caveats check for kernel version "3.10.0-1160.80.1.el7.x86_64" passed, adding "/usr/share/microcode_ctl/ucode_with_caveats/intel-06-55-04" to fw_dir variable
- dracut: microcode_ctl: processing data directory  "/usr/share/microcode_ctl/ucode_with_caveats/intel-06-5e-03"...
- dracut: microcode_ctl: intel-06-5e-03: caveats check for kernel version "3.10.0-1160.80.1.el7.x86_64" passed, adding "/usr/share/microcode_ctl/ucode_with_caveats/intel-06-5e-03" to fw_dir variable
- dracut: microcode_ctl: processing data directory  "/usr/share/microcode_ctl/ucode_with_caveats/intel-06-8c-01"...
- dracut: microcode_ctl: intel-06-8c-01: caveats check for kernel version "3.10.0-1160.80.1.el7.x86_64" passed, adding "/usr/share/microcode_ctl/ucode_with_caveats/intel-06-8c-01" to fw_dir variable
- dracut: microcode_ctl: final fw_dir: "/usr/share/microcode_ctl/ucode_with_caveats/intel-06-8c-01 /usr/share/microcode_ctl/ucode_with_caveats/intel-06-5e-03 /usr/share/microcode_ctl/ucode_with_caveats/intel-06-55-04 /usr/share/microcode_ctl/ucode_with_caveats/intel-06-2d-07 /usr/share/microcode_ctl/ucode_with_caveats/intel /lib/firmware/updates /lib/firmware"
```

The issue happened after upgrading the kernel.
Now, I wonder what the issue is? Is it related to the Grub2 section? Is the new kernel corrupt? ...

I don't know how to instruct Centos 7 to use the previous kernels, because I am just using a rescue machine and cannot run any commands to configure Grub2 or Kernel. But I still have access to files and can run basic commands to list, copy, delete, edit, …

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what is failing but in our `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg`, the first menu entry is the rescue mode entry. We ran a `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg` adtbefore reboot and didn't have issues. Still looking into this as it has affected a few other servers but wanted to give you a workaround for future.